# Not using the Expo fork of react-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo with react native. All is fine, but i get this warning and the app takes a long time  in loading :

```
  [exp] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
```

How can i fix it please.

Comment: How did you setup your project? You should also post your `package.json`. There's not enough information in your question as-is to help you.

Comment: I cloned GeekyAnts/native-base-react-navigation-stack-navigator

Answer (score 36):

If you create a react native app with the command from the getting started page: `$create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` then the package.json file has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^20.0.0",
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react-native": "^0.47.0"
}
```

If you create an app directly in the Expo XDE, you will see in the package.json, they use a fork of react-native:

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^20.0.0",
  "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz"
},
```

Changing the react-native module path to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz and running `npm install` will fix the problem.

Comment: Follow the upgrade instructions to get the correct dependencies for the latest version (v21 now): https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/upgrading-expo.html

Comment: You can find the newest latest version number here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/upgrading-expo.html

Answer (score 2):

That's how I fixed it:

1. I updated my "react-native" dependency to the latest one available:

> "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-23.0.0.tar.gz"

2. I removed all dependency that I had installed by mistake in my previous expo app that actually required react-native link using the npm uninstall --save command:

> react-native-image-to-base64, 
>   react-native-cloudinary

3. Then I also had to remove them from the General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries

Now it works! I'm having issues with the Facebook Login now but at least it doesn't crash my app.

Good luck to you.